# In《命中注定我爱你》when someone calls out 陈欣怡's name, why does she reply 有?

Tags: usage

I was recently watching the TV show 命中注定我爱你, episode 1. On [Youtube](https://youtu.be/mjijADvroSU) at ~3:50 someone calls out her name 陈欣怡 and she responds "有". Could that just mean 'I'm here'?

Comment: TV series watchers are familiar with 有人吗？(is anybody here/there?) cf. bkrs: 房子里有人吗？这个位子有人吗？ Is this seat taken? Comparison: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/17616/%E4%B8%8D%E6%AF%94-vs-%E6%B2%A1%E6%9C%89-comparison-usage

Comment: ２examples from weekly TV series 《庭审现场》 confirming 2nd answer，i.e, "present!" usually is ＂到＂（１）20161105 糊涂父母害亲子 time mark ８：１４ （２）20161210 抑郁杀机  time mark 6:40. In both cases this how the defendant  replies to being addressed by the district attorney／public prosecutor/公诉人。

Comment: Actually these are all "have" but in context. You can think this 有 as "this place _has_ 陈欣怡('s presence)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 有 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/128/

**有**

/jau5/ /jau6 /  (jyutping)

/you3/ /you4/   (pinyin)

[粵] jau5 | [國] you3

- [1](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=2532&curpage=1&sample=%E5%BE%88&radiobutton=1&querytarget=2&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=12) [v] have; own; possess | [ant] 冇
- [2] [v] there is; exist; be present

[粵] jau6 | [國] you4

- [adv] variant of 又 (e.g. 二十有六)

When she said "有够平凡" (very ordinary), '有够'(have enough) means  [非常/真的](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=2532&curpage=1&sample=%E5%BE%88&radiobutton=1&querytarget=2&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=12)(very/really)

She yelled "有!"(**present**!) When people was calling her. Which means "I'm Here!"

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention when answering the roll call; it means 'present'.  I suppose e.g. 'yes, sir' is the most equivalent situation. However, oral Chinese conventions differ from district to district; as far as I know, we usually say '到' when counted.